# HAProxy httpcheck parameters

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

I have a backend in TCP mode and I want to do the health check through a http server.

How can pass the server and port getting checked into my URI?

Thank you!

Comment: Please give more information about your configuration. Why must you use TCP mode? How are you setting up health checking?

Comment: Hello,

The servers I want to load balance are using TCP Sockets. Unfortunately, using option tcp-check send <string> does not work because of the work the messages are processed on those servers. I wanted to centralize the health check on 1 HTTP server, but I actually made a HTTP server backend for each tcp server and it will httpcheck there instead. That solution works

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should work

```
backend app1
    option httpchk GET /ping HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:\ app.mydomain.com
    server backup-app1 xx.xx.xx.xx:80 backup
    server app1 xx.xx.xx.xx:80 check inter 5000 weight 1
```

Comment: Actually what I want is that xx.xx.xx.xx:<port> gets as a GET parameter to the httpchk command